# Any one familiar with this PAServer - Platform Assistant Server error

Tags: delphi, paserver

I recently upgraded my Xcode to the latest version of 8.0, when I tried to update the SDK under Delphi, I go the following error and PAServer shutdown:

```
>libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type BadImage: Invalid image
Abort trap: 6
```

I tried removing the entire SDK and adding it again, didn't help, this is the SDK for the iOS Device, any thoughts? I already have a backup for the Windows development virtual machine (Thankfully).

Comment: Xcode 8 not fully work with delphi berlin :( in fact i learn to never update anything except you have serious reason to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update 1 of Delphi 10.1 Berlin has specific iOS 10 support

Comment: And it is released now :)

Answer (score 0):

No worries, seems like an issue with PAServer:
https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=229561&tstart=0
Thanks to Dave for posting this to Embarcadero